# How do I connect a MySQL database to a GWT app in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, gwt

I need to connect a MySQL database to a really simple GWT app I'm building. 
The thing is, I just cannot find any concrete examples to understand how the connection works in this framework. I need to access some objects info and retrieve it, if possible, as POJO. Nothing too complicated to do with a DAO in a regular Java servlet. 
To be specific, I'd need a button to take the info in two textboxes, and look something up in the database, and write the data in a text box. How should I go about implementing this?

I understand this is a beginner's question and I probably got some concepts wrong, but I need to understand this in the simplest way possible.

Comment: Maybe errai is a good solution, GWT is not a full framework nowadays, or at least you need to choose between too many options, which make it a bit confusing. OTOH, errai choose most of this option for you in a nice working full feature web framework. Take a look at https://github.com/errai/errai-tutorial

Comment: on which server you are going to deploy your application , see if you can create a data source there , you can connect to my sql DB - either via JDBC connection or via datasource - you may choose any option - try and search about both of them , with JDBC approach - you need to handle the connection , with data-source approach you need not handle the connection

Comment: answer explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155300/how-to-correctly-implement-a-dao-in-a-gwt-web-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded connecting MySQL by calling it directly in the Presenter, and not using a DAO. I was trying to access it from the client with a DAO which was wrong.